# Testing jquery dialog with capybara-webkit

Tags: webkit, rspec, integration-testing, capybara, jquery-dialog

I want to test an interaction where the user clicks a link and a jquery dialog (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) pops up.

I would like to test:

1. That the dialog shows up
2. That text in the dialog box is correct
3. That the user can exit by clicking the 'x'

I tested the dialog manually and it works but I am interested in how I would write the actual spec. I would like to do this using Capybara-webkit, but I haven't been able to find code samples for actually using Capybara-webkit.

I am using Capybara-webkit and specs but not cucumber.

Comment: +1, I am having trouble understanding how to use click events with capybara-webkit. My .click() binding doesn't seem to apply in the test, but works in browser

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this:

## Resources

- [Railscasts Episode 257: Request Specs and Capybara](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara)
- [Capybara-webkit on Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)

### Installation

Make sure your Gemfile includes capybara-webkit, rspec-rails, and database_cleaner:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 0.7.2'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.6.7'
end
```

You need database_cleaner because database transactions aren’t compatible with rspec drivers besides Rack::Test:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

#...

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

You must still use the :js => true flag in your tests. Turns out, it's not a selenium-only feature:

```
describe "Something" do
  it "uses javascript", :js => true do
     pending "write a test"
  end
end
```

And, of course, `require 'capybara/rspec'` and set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit` in your spec_helper:

```
#...

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

#...
```

That should be all it takes to get capybara-webkit and rspec up and running.

Comment: thanks for this help. Now, HOW do I test the content inside the dialog (that pops up after clicking the link...)? page.has_selector does not work because that still has original (non popup content)

Comment: If it's a dialog created by html then you should be able to test page.has_content or something... with :js => true... if it's  JS confirm() then I'm not entirely sure